# Deploy separate k8s manifest files

Tags: kubernetes

I have a Spring boot application and I deploy the application to Kubernetes using a single k8s.yml manifest file via Github actions. This k8s.yml manifest contains Secrets, Service, Ingress, Deployment configurations. I was able to deploy the application successfully as well. Now I plan to separate the Secrets, Service, Ingress, Deployment configurations into a separate file as secrets.yml, service.yml, ingress.yml and deployment.yml.

Previously I use the below command for deployment

```
kubectl: 1.5.4
command: |
    sed -e 's/$SEC/${{ secrets.SEC }}/g' -e 's/$APP/${{ env.APP_NAME }}/g' -e 's/$ES/${{ env.ES }}/g' deployment.yml | kubectl apply -f -
```

Now after the separation I use the below commands

```
kubectl: 1.5.4
command: |
  kubectl apply -f secrets.yml
  kubectl apply -f service.yml
  sed -e 's/$ES/${{ env.ES }}/g' ingress.yml | kubectl apply -f -
  sed -e 's/$SEC/${{ secrets.SEC }}/g' -e 's/$APP/${{ env.APP_NAME }}/g' deployment.yml | kubectl apply -f -
```

But some how the application is not deploying correctly, I would like to know if the command which I am using is correct or not

Comment: What does the log says?

Comment: Error: couldn't find key username in Secret

Comment: @Will do you think my commands are correct

Comment: That seems like you might need to perform the replacement on the `secrets.yml` file too.  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve], including the specific YAML manifest that's having the problem and the specific error?  The setup you show seems like a good match for [Helm](https://helm.sh) as a deployment tool, which would let you `helm install` multiple files in a single command and has a built-in template engine.

Answer (score 2):

You can consider perform the `sed` first, then apply all files `kubectl apply -f .` instead of going one by one. Append `--recursive` if you have files in sub folder to apply, too.

Comment: Can you give me an example

Answer (score 1):

Like the other answer says, you can ask kubectl to apply all files recursively in a directory.

Now the `sed` replaces are soon going to become overwhelming as the resources and configuration grow.

That is why `kubctl` comes with integrated [kustomize](https://kustomize.io/) support:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/kustomization/

In short:

1. Break up all kubernetes resources into smaller files/components, put them in a directory.
2. Place a file called `kustomization.yaml` in same directory.
3. In the `kustomization.yaml` configure which file you want to apply, in which order, and also do some on-the-fly edits.

And apply with `-k` flag:

```bash
kubectl apply -k <kustomization_directory>
```